# SVN/python library

Tags: python, svn

I need to manipulate a subversion client from python. I need to:

- check the most recent revision to change something under a given path.
- update a client to a given (head or non head) revision
- get logs for a given path (revisions that changed it and when).

A [quick search](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=subversion) didn't turn up what I'm looking for and I'd rather not have to write my own wrapper around the svn command line tool. (BTW: running under Linux and python 2.6)

Answer (score 6):

Check out the [pysvn](http://pysvn.tigris.org/) library.  Or skim the [pysvn Programmer's Guide](http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_guide.html) to see if it meets most of your use cases.

Comment: Looks like it has what I want.